# Solve differential equation centering in 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Hi I try solve the following problem of differential equation

$$ x''+tx'+\frac{1}{1+t+t^2}x=0 $$

I have to solve that differential equation using power series centering in 1, but I do not know how could solve because I have problem to calculate de coeficient when I said that $$ x(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(t-1)^n$$

help me, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose i make a change of variable $t-1 = s,\space t = s+1$ and denote the derivative with respect to $s$ by $\cdot.$  we have the regular equation $$\ddot x+(s+1)\dot x+\frac1{3+3s+s^2} x = 0. $$ now look for solutions in the form $$x = a_0 + a_1s + a_2s^2 + a_3s^3+\cdots $$ we have $$(3+3s+s^2)\left(1 \cdot 2 a_2+2\cdot3a_3 s+3\cdot 4 a_4s^2+\cdots\right)+(1+s)(3+3s+s^2)\left(a_1+2a_2s+3a_3s^2+\cdots\right)+  a_0 + a_1s + a_2s^2 + a_3s^3+\cdots=0$$

equation the coefficeints of the powers of $s$ to zero we have:
$$\begin{align}6a_2 + 3a_1+a_0&=0\\
3\cdot 2 \cdot 3a_3+3 \cdot 1 \cdot 2a_2+3 \cdot 2 a_2 + 6a_1+a_1 &= 0 \\\vdots\end{align} $$

keeping $a_0, a_1$ arbitrary to account for the initial conditions, we can find al the coefficients $a_2, a_3, \cdots$ recursively.